# Generic string to integer conversion in F#

Tags: generics, f#

I'm implementing a simple conversion string to integer convertor in F#; the logic is, e.g from `string` to `uint32`:

```ml
let inline sToUint s =
    let mutable v = 0u

    for c in s do
        v <- v * 10u + uint32 c - uint32 '0'

    v
```

Now I would like to use this implementation for other integer types, e.g. `uint64`. How can I implement a single generic function to do that?

*Thank for all, SRTP (as used in the answers) is what I need for such a situation. The following implementation is just slightly changed from the answer of @Brian Berns*

```ml
// (char -> ^a) -> (string -> ^b)
let inline sToNum f =
    let tenTimes v = (v <<< 3) + (v <<< 1)
    fun (s: string) ->
        let mutable v = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
        for c in s do
            v <- (tenTimes v) + f c - f '0'
        v
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```ml
let inline sToNum f =
    let ten = Seq.replicate 10 LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne |> Seq.sum
    fun s ->
        let mutable v = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
        for c in s do
            v <- v * ten + f c - f '0'
        v

let sToUint16 = sToNum uint16
let sToUint32 = sToNum uint32
let sToUint64 = sToNum uint64
let sToInt16 = sToNum int16
let sToInt32 = sToNum int32
let sToInt64 = sToNum int64
```

Test code:

```ml
sToUint16 "123" |> printfn "%A"   // 123us
sToUint32 "123" |> printfn "%A"   // 123u
sToUint64 "123" |> printfn "%A"   // 123UL
sToInt16 "123" |> printfn "%A"    // 123s
sToInt32 "123" |> printfn "%A"    // 123
sToInt64 "123" |> printfn "%A"    // 123L
```

Note that `sToNum` returns a lambda, so it doesn't have to recompute `ten` each time. (You could even cache the value of `f '0'` as well, to shave off a little more time.)

Answer (score 2):

If it's done for practical reasons, it's better to use [SRTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) to create function that could be used to parse anything that have static method `Parse: string -> ^a`

```ml
let inline parse (input: string) : ^a =
    ( ^a: (static member Parse: string -> ^a) (input))

(parse "123" : int) |> printfn "%A"
(parse "123" : int64) |> printfn "%A"
(parse "123" : byte) |> printfn "%A"
(parse "123" : int16) |> printfn "%A"
(parse "123" : float32) |> printfn "%A"
(parse "123" : double) |> printfn "%A"
(parse "123" : string) |> printfn "%A" // fails to compile, as string doesn't have Parse method
```

Note that `parse` throws exception if input in invalid format. To be able to handle that, you can use `TryParse` [active pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns)

```ml
let inline (|TryParse|_|) (input: string) : ^a option =
    let mutable result = Unchecked.defaultof< ^a >
    let success = ( ^a: (static member TryParse: string * ^a byref -> bool) (input, &result))
    if success then
        Some result
    else
        None

match "123" with
| TryParse (a : int) -> printfn "it's int %d" a
| TryParse (a : int64) -> printfn "it's very big int %d" a
| TryParse (a : float) -> printfn "it's double %f" a
| x -> printfn "it's something I can't handle: %s" x
```

Note that both functions will use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` as default. They can be edited to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, but I will leave it for homework

Comment: Thank you for pointing out SRTP, it's a correct direction for such a kind of problem. I didn't know about that.